# How to make code look elegant in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, I have read blogs on how Haskell code is very elegant. The way I am writing Haskell code, it does not look elegant at all.
Some of the areas I want to improve are

- I use case matches on Either values a lot, is using something like
  fromRight from Data.Either a better option? I also have some code with nested structures, for right values

  ```
  case eitherResponse of
      Right response -> return $ toJSON $ response
      Left msg -> Log $ "Error" <> msg
  ```
- I have a lot of code which looks like this

  ```
  fname <- URI.mkPathPiece functionname
  kch <- URI.mkPathPiece $ T.pack "channel"
  vch <- URI.mkPathPiece channel
  kca <- URI.mkPathPiece $ T.pack "chaincode"
  vca <- URI.mkPathPiece chaincode
  let path = Just (True, Data.List.NonEmpty.fromList [fname, kch, vch, kca, vca])
  ```

I really do not like the way it looks, how can I improve this?

Also, Haskell for me is very similar to imperative programming in a "do" block. Is that how Haskell code should look or I am on the wrong track here?

Comment: The thing is , If  I have a top level function in IO ,every function that I write under it needs to be in IO ,so by the time I am done , every function that I have written ends up returning IO / some Monad Trasformer stack type values . It works for me , I just want to understand if this is a good practice ?

Comment: Can you add the full code?

Comment: Not really a significant thing, but with `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` I think you can skip the `T.pack` and just do `URI.mkPathPiece "channel"`.

Comment: And then there’s something like `foo <- mapM URI.mkPathPiece $ NonEmpty.fromList [functionname, "channel", channel, "chaincode", chaincode]` (use `import qualified`)

Comment: @Ry- very nice contribution, I added to my answer if you don't mind, thanks!

Comment: Would this question be better served in the code review section of stack exchange?

Comment: Oh, the mapM... Thats exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: “If I have a top level function in IO ,every function that I write under it needs to be in IO” – **no**, what made you think so? It's the other way around, if some particular function needs `IO` than _the top-level function that calls it_ also needs to be `IO`. But all the other functions it calls can be normal pure functions just fine, if _they_ don't need `IO`.

Answer (score 3):

You can improve your second example like this:

```
pieces <- traverse URI.makePathPiece $ 
   NonEmpty.fromList [functionName, "channel", channel, "chaincode", chaincode]
let path = Just (True, pieces)
```

We omit the `T.pack`s by using the `{-# OverloadedStrings #-}` extension.  Then use `traverse` to map a monadic function over a `NonEmpty`, which is a traversable container.

I need more context to give a concrete alternative to the first example, but if you have nested structures such as:

```
case eitherResponse of
    Left -> some error ...
    Right x -> 
        case someFunction x of
            Left -> some error ...
            Right y -> ...
```

This kind of chaining is exactly what `Either`/`ExceptT`'s `Monad` instances do.   You can make it look like this:

```
do x <- eitherResponse
   y <- someFunction x
```

Time to learn about monad transformers!

Answer (score 2):

I just can think in improve a little this part with a subfunction kind of helper function:

```
toJsonOrError (Right response) = return $ toJSON $ response
toJsonOrError (Left msg) = Log $ "Error" <> msg
```

Also you can import qualified as @Ri- pointed, to replace Data.List.NonEmpty.fromList like:

```
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NonEmpty (fromList)
```

to simplify the line:

```
Just (True, fromList [fname, kch, vch, kca, vca])
```

The rest of your code is `do` notation and doesn't look like it can be improved (at leas with the code you've shown)